# Google API Error : User profile request failed! Google returned an invalid response

Tags: magento2, error, google-api, http-status-403

**I'm using Social Login Extension in Magento 226 trying to login with Google but it's showing below error.**

> Ooophs, we got an error: User profile request failed! Google returned
>   an invalid response:stdClass::__set_state(array( 'error' =>
>   stdClass::__set_state(array( 'code' => 403, 'message' => 'Legacy
>   People API has not been used in project 36088930720 before or it is
>   disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=36088930720
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.', 'status' =>
>   'PERMISSION_DENIED', 'details' => array ( 0 =>
>   stdClass::__set_state(array( '@type' =>
>   'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links' => array ( 0 =>
>   stdClass::__set_state(array( 'description' => 'Google developers
>   console API activation', 'url' =>
>   'https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=36088930720',
>   )), ), )), ), )), ))

**Sometimes Error Changes to below error,**

> Ooophs, we got an error: User profile request failed! Google returned
>   an invalid response:stdClass::__set_state(array( 'error' =>
>   stdClass::__set_state(array( 'code' => 401, 'message' => 'Request had
>   invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token,
>   login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See
>   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.',
>   'status' => 'UNAUTHENTICATED', )), ))

**Things I've tried but didn't work,**

- I've tried visiting URL that suggested in Error but it shows 
  [image: URL Error]
- Creating new Credentials.
- Tried enabling google+, contacts, script
  APIs.

**Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found an answer by myself after some digging. I did some changes to the Hybrid Library file. Make sure you enable [Google People API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/people.googleapis.com?q=googlepeople&id=5877a7af-1d13-4098-a53e-b5e2d7a87a4f&project=mageants-social-login) as [Google+ APIs have been Shutdown](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown).

**Before changes, the code was as followed,**

> **Hybrid/Providers/Google.php**

```
<?php

/* !
 * HybridAuth
 * http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net | http://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth
 * (c) 2009-2015, HybridAuth authors | http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/licenses.html
 */

/**
 * Hybrid_Providers_Google provider adapter based on OAuth2 protocol
 *
 * http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Google.html
 */
class Hybrid_Providers_Google extends Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2 {

    /**
     * > more infos on google APIs: http://developer.google.com (official site)
     * or here: http://discovery-check.appspot.com/ (unofficial but up to date)
     * default permissions
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();

        // Provider api end-points
        $this->api->authorize_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
        $this->api->token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        $this->api->token_info_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo";

        // Google POST methods require an access_token in the header
        $this->api->curl_header = array("Authorization: OAuth " . $this->api->access_token);

        // Override the redirect uri when it's set in the config parameters. This way we prevent
        // redirect uri mismatches when authenticating with Google.
        if (isset($this->config['redirect_uri']) && !empty($this->config['redirect_uri'])) {
            $this->api->redirect_uri = $this->config['redirect_uri'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function loginBegin() {
        $parameters = array("scope" => $this->scope, "access_type" => "offline");
        $optionals = array("scope", "access_type", "redirect_uri", "approval_prompt", "hd", "state");

        foreach ($optionals as $parameter) {
            if (isset($this->config[$parameter]) && !empty($this->config[$parameter])) {
                $parameters[$parameter] = $this->config[$parameter];
            }
            if (isset($this->config["scope"]) && !empty($this->config["scope"])) {
                $this->scope = $this->config["scope"];
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->config['force']) && $this->config['force'] === true) {
            $parameters['approval_prompt'] = 'force';
        }

        Hybrid_Auth::redirect($this->api->authorizeUrl($parameters));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function getUserProfile() {
        // refresh tokens if needed
        $this->refreshToken();

        // ask google api for user infos
        if (strpos($this->scope, '/auth/plus.profile.emails.read') !== false) {
            $verified = $this->api->api("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");

            if (!isset($verified->id) || isset($verified->error))
                $verified = new stdClass();
        } else {
            $verified = $this->api->api("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect");

            if (!isset($verified->sub) || isset($verified->error))
                $verified = new stdClass();
        }

        $response = $this->api->api("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");
        if (!isset($response->id) || isset($response->error)) {
            throw new Exception("User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid response:" . Hybrid_Logger::dumpData( $response ), 6);
        }

        $this->user->profile->identifier = (property_exists($verified, 'id')) ? $verified->id : ((property_exists($response, 'id')) ? $response->id : "");
        $this->user->profile->firstName = (property_exists($response, 'name')) ? $response->name->givenName : "";
        $this->user->profile->lastName = (property_exists($response, 'name')) ? $response->name->familyName : "";
        $this->user->profile->displayName = (property_exists($response, 'displayName')) ? $response->displayName : "";
        $this->user->profile->photoURL = (property_exists($response, 'image')) ? ((property_exists($response->image, 'url')) ? substr($response->image->url, 0, -2) . "200" : '') : '';
        $this->user->profile->profileURL = (property_exists($response, 'url')) ? $response->url : "";
        $this->user->profile->description = (property_exists($response, 'aboutMe')) ? $response->aboutMe : "";
        $this->user->profile->gender = (property_exists($response, 'gender')) ? $response->gender : "";
        $this->user->profile->language = (property_exists($response, 'locale')) ? $response->locale : ((property_exists($verified, 'locale')) ? $verified->locale : "");
        $this->user->profile->email = (property_exists($response, 'email')) ? $response->email : ((property_exists($verified, 'email')) ? $verified->email : "");
        $this->user->profile->emailVerified = (property_exists($verified, 'email')) ? $verified->email : "";
        if (property_exists($response, 'emails')) {
            if (count($response->emails) == 1) {
                $this->user->profile->email = $response->emails[0]->value;
            } else {
                foreach ($response->emails as $email) {
                    if ($email->type == 'account') {
                        $this->user->profile->email = $email->value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (property_exists($verified, 'emails')) {
                if (count($verified->emails) == 1) {
                    $this->user->profile->emailVerified = $verified->emails[0]->value;
                } else {
                    foreach ($verified->emails as $email) {
                        if ($email->type == 'account') {
                            $this->user->profile->emailVerified = $email->value;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->user->profile->phone = (property_exists($response, 'phone')) ? $response->phone : "";
        $this->user->profile->country = (property_exists($response, 'country')) ? $response->country : "";
        $this->user->profile->region = (property_exists($response, 'region')) ? $response->region : "";
        $this->user->profile->zip = (property_exists($response, 'zip')) ? $response->zip : "";
        if (property_exists($response, 'placesLived')) {
            $this->user->profile->city = "";
            $this->user->profile->address = "";
            foreach ($response->placesLived as $c) {
                if (property_exists($c, 'primary')) {
                    if ($c->primary == true) {
                        $this->user->profile->address = $c->value;
                        $this->user->profile->city = $c->value;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (property_exists($c, 'value')) {
                        $this->user->profile->address = $c->value;
                        $this->user->profile->city = $c->value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // google API returns multiple urls, but a "website" only if it is verified
        // see http://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713826?hl=en
        if (property_exists($response, 'urls')) {
            foreach ($response->urls as $u) {
                if (property_exists($u, 'primary') && $u->primary == true)
                    $this->user->profile->webSiteURL = $u->value;
            }
        } else {
            $this->user->profile->webSiteURL = '';
        }
        // google API returns age ranges min and/or max as of https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource
        if (property_exists($response, 'ageRange')) {
            if (property_exists($response->ageRange, 'min') && property_exists($response->ageRange, 'max')) {
                $this->user->profile->age = $response->ageRange->min . ' - ' . $response->ageRange->max;
            } else {
                if (property_exists($response->ageRange, 'min')) {
                    $this->user->profile->age = '>= ' . $response->ageRange->min;
                } else {
                    if (property_exists($response->ageRange, 'max')) {
                        $this->user->profile->age = '<= ' . $response->ageRange->max;
                    } else {
                        $this->user->profile->age = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->user->profile->age = '';
        }
        // google API returns birthdays only if a user set 'show in my account'
        if (property_exists($response, 'birthday')) {
            list($birthday_year, $birthday_month, $birthday_day) = explode('-', $response->birthday);

            $this->user->profile->birthDay = (int) $birthday_day;
            $this->user->profile->birthMonth = (int) $birthday_month;
            $this->user->profile->birthYear = (int) $birthday_year;
        } else {
            $this->user->profile->birthDay = 0;
            $this->user->profile->birthMonth = 0;
            $this->user->profile->birthYear = 0;
        }

        return $this->user->profile;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function getUserContacts() {
        // refresh tokens if needed
        $this->refreshToken();
        
        $contacts = array();
        if (!isset($this->config['contacts_param'])) {
            $this->config['contacts_param'] = array("max-results" => 500);
        }
        
        // Google Gmail and Android contacts
        if (strpos($this->scope, '/m8/feeds/') !== false) {
            
            $response = $this->api->api("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?"
                    . http_build_query(array_merge(array('alt' => 'json'), $this->config['contacts_param'])));
            
            if (!$response) {
                return array();
            }
            
            if (isset($response->feed->entry)) {
                foreach ($response->feed->entry as $idx => $entry) {
                    $uc = new Hybrid_User_Contact();
                    $uc->email = isset($entry->{'gd$email'}[0]->address) ? (string) $entry->{'gd$email'}[0]->address : '';
                    $uc->displayName = isset($entry->title->{'$t'}) ? (string) $entry->title->{'$t'} : '';
                    $uc->identifier = ($uc->email != '') ? $uc->email : '';
                    $uc->description = '';
                    if (property_exists($entry, 'link')) {
                        /**
                         * sign links with access_token
                         */
                        if (is_array($entry->link)) {
                            foreach ($entry->link as $l) {
                                if (property_exists($l, 'gd$etag') && $l->type == "image/*") {
                                    $uc->photoURL = $this->addUrlParam($l->href, array('access_token' => $this->api->access_token));
                                } else if ($l->type == "self") {
                                    $uc->profileURL = $this->addUrlParam($l->href, array('access_token' => $this->api->access_token));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $uc->profileURL = '';
                    }
                    if (property_exists($response, 'website')) {
                        if (is_array($response->website)) {
                            foreach ($response->website as $w) {
                                if ($w->primary == true)
                                    $uc->webSiteURL = $w->value;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $uc->webSiteURL = $response->website->value;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $uc->webSiteURL = '';
                    }
                    
                    $contacts[] = $uc;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Google social contacts
        if (strpos($this->scope, '/auth/plus.login') !== false) {
            
            $response = $this->api->api("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?"
                    . http_build_query($this->config['contacts_param']));
            
            if (!$response) {
                return array();
            }
            
            foreach ($response->items as $idx => $item) {
                $uc = new Hybrid_User_Contact();
                $uc->email = (property_exists($item, 'email')) ? $item->email : '';
                $uc->displayName = (property_exists($item, 'displayName')) ? $item->displayName : '';
                $uc->identifier = (property_exists($item, 'id')) ? $item->id : '';
                
                $uc->description = (property_exists($item, 'objectType')) ? $item->objectType : '';
                $uc->photoURL = (property_exists($item, 'image')) ? ((property_exists($item->image, 'url')) ? $item->image->url : '') : '';
                $uc->profileURL = (property_exists($item, 'url')) ? $item->url : '';
                $uc->webSiteURL = '';
                
                $contacts[] = $uc;
            }
        }
        
        return $contacts;
    }
    
    /**
     * Add query parameters to the $url
     *
     * @param string $url    URL
     * @param array  $params Parameters to add
     * @return string
     */
    function addUrlParam($url, array $params){      
        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

        // Returns the URL string with new parameters
        if ($query) {
            $url .= '&' . http_build_query($params);
        } else {
            $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
        }
        return $url;
    }

}
```

**After the changes, which is working code as followed,**

> **Hybrid/Providers/Google.php**

```
<?php

/* !
 * HybridAuth
 * http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net | http://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth
 * (c) 2009-2015, HybridAuth authors | http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/licenses.html
 */

/**
 * Hybrid_Providers_Google provider adapter based on OAuth2 protocol
 *
 * http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_Google.html
 */
class Hybrid_Providers_Google extends Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2 {

    /**
     * > more infos on google APIs: http://developer.google.com (official site)
     * or here: http://discovery-check.appspot.com/ (unofficial but up to date)
     * default permissions
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();

        // Provider api end-points
        $this->api->authorize_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
        $this->api->token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        $this->api->token_info_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo";

        // Google POST methods require an access_token in the header
        $this->api->curl_header = array("Authorization: OAuth " . $this->api->access_token);

        // Override the redirect uri when it's set in the config parameters. This way we prevent
        // redirect uri mismatches when authenticating with Google.
        if (isset($this->config['redirect_uri']) && !empty($this->config['redirect_uri'])) {
            $this->api->redirect_uri = $this->config['redirect_uri'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function loginBegin() {
        $parameters = array("scope" => $this->scope, "access_type" => "offline");
        $optionals = array("scope", "access_type", "redirect_uri", "approval_prompt", "hd", "state");

        foreach ($optionals as $parameter) {
            if (isset($this->config[$parameter]) && !empty($this->config[$parameter])) {
                $parameters[$parameter] = $this->config[$parameter];
            }
            if (isset($this->config["scope"]) && !empty($this->config["scope"])) {
                $this->scope = $this->config["scope"];
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->config['force']) && $this->config['force'] === true) {
            $parameters['approval_prompt'] = 'force';
        }

        Hybrid_Auth::redirect($this->api->authorizeUrl($parameters));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function getUserProfile() {
        // refresh tokens if needed
        $this->refreshToken();

        $response = $this->api->api("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo");
        if (!isset($response->sub) || isset($response->error)) {
            throw new Exception("User profile request failed! {$this->providerId} returned an invalid response:" . Hybrid_Logger::dumpData( $response ), 6);
        }

        $this->user->profile->identifier = (property_exists($response, 'sub')) ? $response->sub : "";
        $this->user->profile->firstName = (property_exists($response, 'given_name')) ? $response->given_name : "";
        $this->user->profile->lastName = (property_exists($response, 'family_name')) ? $response->family_name : "";
        $this->user->profile->displayName = (property_exists($response, 'name')) ? $response->name : "";
        $this->user->profile->photoURL = (property_exists($response, 'picture')) ? $response->picture : "";
        $this->user->profile->profileURL = (property_exists($response, 'profile')) ? $response->profile : "";
        $this->user->profile->gender = (property_exists($response, 'gender')) ? $response->gender : "";
        $this->user->profile->language = (property_exists($response, 'locale')) ? $response->locale : "";
        $this->user->profile->email = (property_exists($response, 'email')) ? $response->email : "";
        $this->user->profile->emailVerified = (property_exists($response, 'email_verified')) ? ($response->email_verified === true || $response->email_verified === 1 ? $response->email : "") : "";

        return $this->user->profile;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function getUserContacts() {
        // refresh tokens if needed
        $this->refreshToken();
        
        $contacts = array();
        if (!isset($this->config['contacts_param'])) {
            $this->config['contacts_param'] = array("max-results" => 500);
        }
        
        // Google Gmail and Android contacts
        if (strpos($this->scope, '/m8/feeds/') !== false) {
            
            $response = $this->api->api("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?"
                    . http_build_query(array_merge(array('alt' => 'json'), $this->config['contacts_param'])));
            
            if (!$response) {
                return array();
            }
            
            if (isset($response->feed->entry)) {
                foreach ($response->feed->entry as $idx => $entry) {
                    $uc = new Hybrid_User_Contact();
                    $uc->email = isset($entry->{'gd$email'}[0]->address) ? (string) $entry->{'gd$email'}[0]->address : '';
                    $uc->displayName = isset($entry->title->{'$t'}) ? (string) $entry->title->{'$t'} : '';
                    $uc->identifier = ($uc->email != '') ? $uc->email : '';
                    $uc->description = '';
                    if (property_exists($entry, 'link')) {
                        /**
                         * sign links with access_token
                         */
                        if (is_array($entry->link)) {
                            foreach ($entry->link as $l) {
                                if (property_exists($l, 'gd$etag') && $l->type == "image/*") {
                                    $uc->photoURL = $this->addUrlParam($l->href, array('access_token' => $this->api->access_token));
                                } else if ($l->type == "self") {
                                    $uc->profileURL = $this->addUrlParam($l->href, array('access_token' => $this->api->access_token));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $uc->profileURL = '';
                    }
                    if (property_exists($response, 'website')) {
                        if (is_array($response->website)) {
                            foreach ($response->website as $w) {
                                if ($w->primary == true)
                                    $uc->webSiteURL = $w->value;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $uc->webSiteURL = $response->website->value;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $uc->webSiteURL = '';
                    }
                    
                    $contacts[] = $uc;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $contacts;
    }
    
    /**
     * Add query parameters to the $url
     *
     * @param string $url    URL
     * @param array  $params Parameters to add
     * @return string
     */
    function addUrlParam($url, array $params){      
        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

        // Returns the URL string with new parameters
        if ($query) {
            $url .= '&' . http_build_query($params);
        } else {
            $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
        }
        return $url;
    }

}
```

**After changing to this code, my google api is working fine.**

Comment: Can you please help me to know , exactly what changes you did

Comment: this is the only file Hybrid/Providers/Google.php I have changed

Comment: mageplaza which version u are using?

Comment: I had used the MagePal module version 1.5.1

Comment: @MohitRane you didn't change the whole file....you have to mention the exact code which you have changed.

Comment: @VishalThakur but if you compare this file with your file I'm sure you will see the changes.

Comment: i already checked it but didn't find any changes... both your file & mageplaza file are same.